# Building electron linux distro : The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly

Tags: linux, tfs, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am generating electron distro for linux.
This is how the app is built
This is how app is built in packge.json

```
 "builderForLinx": "electron-packager --out linx64 --overwrite --platform linux --appname myApp --asar"
```

this app structure myApp -> myApp(the linux executable), mian.js, resources -> myApp.asar

This gives an linux version electron package. But I have to run the following commands to run the app

```
sudo chmod +x ./myApp
sudo chown root chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox
```

Actually I get the app from tfs build artifact and when I download this app, I want to directly run ./myApp.

This is my tfs definition, I run all these in bash, not my agent/build machines are windows ones.

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/myApp" ; pwd
chown <<username>> chrome-sandbox
chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox
```

Note : $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) is the tfs variable which points to artifact directory.
When I run the app directly in linux machine I see this error

```
The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /home/staff/kjeeva/licregsNew/v211/licensingclient/linx64/ClientSettings-asar/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
```

I am not well versed with linux environment, any help or suggestions on this will be great help.

Comment: Note the electron app is genarated as .TGZ file, when I tar and untar I want the file permssion to be retained

Comment: For example chrome-sandbox needs to have -rwsr-xr-x and all others must have -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: when I tar the package and untar I want it to have same file permissions

Comment: Hi friend, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Also, feel free to let me know if you're still blocked~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`The SUID sandbox helper binary was found ...` seems to be one hot issue about electron  framework in Linux. You can check [this discussion](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17972) for more details.

Here're the available workarounds from that discussion:

1.chown and chmod the file first like what you did.

```
sudo chown root chrome-sandbox
chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox
```

2.If you get one appimage, you can run it directly with `--no-sandbox arguemnt`

3.`sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` to [enable unprivileged access](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17972#issuecomment-486927073).

You've already used `#1`, but you can also check if `#2/#3` is more suitable for your scenario.

> This is my tfs definition, I run all these in bash, not my agent/build
> machines are windows ones.

Since part of your agents are Linux and others are Windows, I recommend you can use [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=yaml) to manage the bash tasks. You can have two different bash tasks/steps, one for Linux and another for Windows. And then set their conditions to run correct commands conditionally. Something like this:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write commands here
      # ...
  displayName: 'Bash command for Linux'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux'))

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write commands here
      # ...
  displayName: 'Bash command for Windows'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT'))
```

About predefined variable `Agent.OS`, you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables).