# Ubuntu Linux returns an error with the SUID sandbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, electron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

I'm having trouble entering the command 'npm start'.

The exact error message was:

```
The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, 
but is not configured correctly. 
Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to reinstall electron with npm_config_platform=win32 as suggested at the [following link](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17972#issuecomment-958110165) on Electron bugtracker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building electron linux distro : The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780918/building-electron-linux-distro-the-suid-sandbox-helper-binary-was-found-but-i)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow -- I see you are receiving a lot of downvotes on the question, so I would highly recommend you read a couple of links -- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially "Search, and research ...."  What have you found when searching for the error?  What have you tried?  Also please read [why we ask that you not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you can try:

1 - Reinstall

2 - run it with the launch argument `--no-sandbox`

3 - Enable unprivileged access to `CLONE_NEWUSER` in you kernel;
`sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1`